# How to wait for next @Composable function in jetpack compose test?

Tags: user-interface, testing, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have 3 @Composable functions: Start, Loading, Result.

In the test, I call the **Start** function, click the **Begin** button on it, and the **Loading** function is called.

The **Loading** function displays the loading procedure, takes some time, and then calls the **Result** function.

The **Result** function renders a field with the text **OK**.

How to wait in the test for the **Result**  or few seconds function to be drawn and check that the text is rendered **OK**?

```
composeTestRule
    .onNodeWithText("Begin")
    .performClick()

// Here you have to wait ...

composeTestRule
    .onNodeWithText("OK")
    .assertIsDisplayed()
```

Comment: Check if `composeTestRule.waitUntil(timeoutMs) { condition }` works for your scenario

Comment: Tried to apply this method but couldn't find a matching condition.

I tried to write a check in the condition if the widget with the text "OK" was displayed, but there is a type mismatch, boolean is required there.

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes condition should be a boolean, can be fixed by using composeTestRule.waitUntil(timeoutMs) { condition } where condition can be something like =>>> rule.onAllNodesWithContentDescription("Something")
                .fetchSemanticsNodes().isEmpty()
you can play with these with something visible on your screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the options are:

1. It is possible to write to the global variable which function was last called. The disadvantage is that you will need to register in each function.
2. Subscribe to the state of the screen through the viewmodel and track when it comes. The disadvantage is that you will need to pull the viewmodel into the test and know the code. The plus is that the test is quickly executed and does not get stuck, as is the case with a timer.
3. I made this choice. I wrote a function for starting an asynchronous timer, that is, the application is running, the test waits, and after the timer ends, it continues checking in the test. The disadvantage is that you set a timer with a margin of time to complete the operation and the test takes a long time to idle. The advantage is that you don't have to dig into the source code.

Implemented the function like this.

```
fun asyncTimer (delay: Long = 1000) {
    AsyncTimer.start (delay)
    composeTestRule.waitUntil (
        condition = {AsyncTimer.expired},
        timeoutMillis = delay + 1000
    )
}

object AsyncTimer {
    var expired = false
    fun start(delay: Long = 1000){
        expired = false
        Timer().schedule(delay) {
            expired = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a base class for the test and starting to write a new test, I inherit and I have the necessary ready-made functionality for tests.

Comment: I think for pure Compose this is not the best option but I found it's very useful for when non Compose UI like a date picker doesn't seem to behave. This code works perfectly in that use case until we can get a Compose date picker. It's so weird; without a sleep like this it presses things that I never told it to press. It will even randomly select the wrong date or press other buttons! Sometimes it intermittently can't find the thing it needs to press. I guess it's some sort of bug but this timer just before I ask it to select something fixes it - at least as a workaround for now. Thanks :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#custom-semantics-properties example for datepicker

Comment: I'm not using it for assertions I need it to click things. I don't think that reference is what I need.

Comment: I think next month I will need to work with the date selection, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 18):

Edit: there are new waitUntil functions:

```kotlin
fun waitUntilAtLeastOneExists(matcher: SemanticsMatcher, timeout: Long = 1000L)

fun waitUntilDoesNotExist(matcher: SemanticsMatcher, timeout: Long = 1000L)

fun waitUntilExactlyOneExists(matcher: SemanticsMatcher,  timeout: Long = 1000L)

fun waitUntilNodeCount(matcher: SemanticsMatcher, count: Int, timeout: Long = 1000L)
```

---

You can use the [`waitUntil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/ComposeTestRule#waitUntil(kotlin.Long,kotlin.Function0)) function, as suggested in the comments:

```kotlin
composeTestRule.waitUntil {
    composeTestRule
        .onAllNodesWithText("OK")
        .fetchSemanticsNodes().size == 1
}
```

There's a [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/226934294) to improve this API but in the meantime you can get the helpers from [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/alternatives-to-idling-resources-in-compose-tests-8ae71f9fc473) and use it like so:

```kotlin
composeTestRule.waitUntilExists(hasText("OK"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Pitry's answer I created this extension function:

```
fun ComposeContentTestRule.waitUntilTimeout(
    timeoutMillis: Long
) {
    AsyncTimer.start(timeoutMillis)
    this.waitUntil(
        condition = { AsyncTimer.expired },
        timeoutMillis = timeoutMillis + 1000
    )
}

object AsyncTimer {
    var expired = false
    fun start(delay: Long = 1000) {
        expired = false
        Timer().schedule(delay) {
            expired = true
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in compose test

```
composeTestRule.waitUntilTimeout(2000L)
```

Comment: Whick Timer packe to import? none works.

Comment: java.util.Timer

Answer (score 0):

I modified per_jansson's reply.

```
fun ComposeContentTestRule.waitUntilTimeout(
    timeoutMillis: Long
) {
    AsyncTimer.start(timeoutMillis)
    this.waitUntil(
        condition = { AsyncTimer.expired },
        timeoutMillis = timeoutMillis + 1000
    )
}

object AsyncTimer {
    var expired = false
    fun start(delay: Long = 1000) {
        expired = false
        val timerTask = TimerTaskImpl {
            expired = true
        }
        Timer().schedule(timerTask, delay)
    }
}

class TimerTaskImpl(private val runnable: Runnable) : TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
        runnable.run()
    }
}
```

`TimerTask` is an abstract class, and when I copied and pasted per_jansson's code, it didn't work for me